# Split pod replicas across the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have 3 nodes in my cluster: a) OnDemand b) Spot and c) Spot

OnDemand node has toleration, as I want to have some of my important nodes on this in demand node. From other side - I want to have replicas for my nodes (replicaCount: 2) and I want to place replica on SPOT node.

I added this config for my deployment:

```
tolerations:
  - key: dev-group
    value: OnDemand
    effect: NoSchedule

affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType
          operator: In
          values:
          - ON_DEMAND
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 1
      preference:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType
          operator: In
          values:
          - SPOT
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
            - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
              operator: In
              values:
              - [app-name]
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

1. I expect that I allowed place the pod on OnDemand node (I added "exception" for toleration)
2. I defined that I require to run my pod on the ON_DEMAND node
3. I defined that I preferred to run also it on SPOT node

So, it is like - I restricted pods to be at ON_DEMAND but also allowed to use SPOT

4. I require to not have the same pods on the same node

But for some reason I have this error:

```
0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules, 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/select or. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
```

What I am missing?

I double checked - my node has lables:

```
eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=SPOT
and
eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
```

My toleration is working, because if I exclude `podAntiAffinity` - my pods will be placed on ON_DEMAND node.

What is wrong?

Comment: I'm having trouble following your description. You say that the on-demand node has a toleration? Nodes can only be tainted. Pods can have tolerations. I assume you meant to say "pod". Are you basically trying to spread the pods in your deployment across the 2 spot nodes?

Comment: Your node affinity rules appear to conflict with each other; the scheduler can't satisfy both conditions, i.e. require a pod to be scheduled on an on-demand node and prefer it run on Spot.

Comment: One pod must be run at ON_DEMAND. This is why I am using required. Second pod (repllica) must run at any SPOT. This is why I am used preffered (without it - pod cant be allowed to be at SPOT). And podAntiAffinity should split pods at different nodes. This is my logic. Maybe I need to review these rules. And yes, you are right about toleration!